# Return any type of object from a function

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Is there any way of returning an object from a function. The tricky part is the object can be of any type. I want a function to handle returning objects from session. So the object i want to return could be a product one minute but then i might want to return a customer the next minute. Is it possible or will I have to do a function to return each type.

Comment: Note: A function that returns a Product the first time, then a Customer the next, is probably a pretty bad design.  At the very least, it's by definition doing two quite different things.  (Unless they both extend/implement the same interface, in which case you could just declare your function to return that.)

Comment: http://benohead.com/create-anonymous-types-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 6):

1. Return `object` it's the highest class.
2. Make the Method generic.
3. Return `dynamic` (thanks to @AustinSalonen)

---

```
public T Foo<T>(T obj)
{
    var variable = GetTFromFooElse();
    return variable; 
}
```

---

```
public dynamic Foo()
{
    var variable = GetSomethingFromFooElse();
    return variable;
}
```

Comment: These answers just push the casting around - and don't really solve the askers deeper question

Comment: @DaveBish. Which is? I think the generic answer is what is being used in all ORM frameworks...

Comment: @DaveBish. I didn't notice where he asked how to pull values from the session, but... you wrote it in your answer, if that's what he wants he can read it there. cheers.

Comment: Sure, but it's pointless - as Session[] already returns an object ;)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can return ***Type object***. Though, you'll need to cast the result in the caller to use anything remotely useful.

```
static object CarFactory (){
    return new Car();
}

static void Main(){

    Car car = (Car)CarFactory();

    /* do stuff with car */
    car.Crash();
}
```

---

*Note* It is a standard to use generics as it provides the desired level of abstraction with Type safety...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use cade, instead of using object maybe you could use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that?

Have a class `Session<T>` with a method

```
T GetResult()
```

You could the make instances like this:

```
var x = new Session<Product>();
var y = new Session<Customer>();
```

This way you get some nice type safety.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of scenario, you're better off wrapping up your session class via some kind of Service/Api.

For example:

```
public static class SessionAccess
{
    public static Something SomethingSession
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["Something"] as Something;
        }

        set
        {
            Session["Something"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It's important to have a consistent session-access mechanism, as to avoid accidentally stepping-over the same session key, and to ensure it's always the same underlying datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If your method returns an Object you can return any object you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your method can return a **object**, but you must convert for the object you want when you call it.